# How to get multiple user input for 30 seconds & save it into list?

Tags: python

In my application user can input for 30 seconds and also user can input as many words he want.

I want to save all words into list entered by user within 30 seconds.

I have surfed on websites & stackoverflow also but found that most of solution works only on linux & other are not so relavant for me so I need to raise question.

I have tried below code also but still it is not fulfilling my requirement.

```
import sys, time, msvcrt

def readInput( caption, default, timeout = 2000):
    start_time = time.time()
    sys.stdout.write('%s(%s):'%(caption, default));
    input = ''
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            chr = msvcrt.getche()
            if ord(chr) == 13: # enter_key
                break
            elif ord(chr) >= 32: #space_char
                input += chr
        if len(input) == 0 and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            break

    print ''  # needed to move to next line
    if len(input) > 0:
        return input
    else:
        return default

# and some examples of usage
ans = readInput('Please type a name', 'john') 
print 'The name is %s' % ans
```

Comment: In what way(s) is the posted code "not filling your requirement"?

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
import time
user_input_list = []
timeOut = False
start_time = time.time()


def readInput():
    global user_input_list
    while timeOut == False:
        user_input_list.append(input("Please enter your input: "))
    return print("User input list is ", user_input_list)


def countTime(seconds):
    global start_time
    global timeOut
    while True:
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if elapsed_time == seconds:
            timeOut = True
            return print("Elapsed time is ", elapsed_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=readInput).start()
    Thread(target=countTime(20)).start()
```

Edit:
I defined two function. First function keeps track of user input, and second one counts the time. When time is up, `countTime` function makes `timeout` `False` so that `readInput` function stops looping, and both functions return their variables.